# complex triple join with condition rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

I'm pretty new to rails but it feels good to see that I progress however I'm facing my first real complex model problem :/

Here is how my models look like :

```
class Top < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_tops, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :ideas, :through => :line_tops
  has_many :top_subscriptions
  has_many :users, :through => :top_subscriptions

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :top_suscribtions
  has_many :tops, :through => :top_suscribtions
  has_many :idea_suscribtions
  has_many :ideas, :through => :idea_suscribtions

class IdeaSubscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :idea
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :idea, :user, :done (is a boolean)
```

I want to retrieve for a top, all users who have done all ideas (done=true) of this top.
I'm quite lost as I don't really know what should I do. A new attribute in top model or a method ? Can I do it with active record query interface or should i use pure sql ?
What is the 'best' way to achieve this ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Not tested, but how about `top.users.where(['not exists (select i_s.done from ideas i join idea_subscriptions i_s on i_s.idea_id=i.id join line_tops lt on lt.idea_id=i.id where i_s.user_id=users.id and i_s.done=0 and lt.top_id=?) and exists (select i_s.done from ideas i join idea_subscriptions i_s on i_s.idea_id=i.id join line_tops lt on lt.idea_id=i.id where i_s.user_id=users.id and i_s.done=1 and lt.top_id=?)', top.id, top.id])`? See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The query works but show no result (it should i check the condition in my database). Maybe it's because done is stored as 't' or 'f' in my sqlite database ? There is no much pretty way to do this ? :p

Comment: OK so if you change 0/1 to 'f'/'t' do you still get wrong results?

Comment: Yep it works ^^ I'll go with the accepted answer as it is prettier. Thanks for your help ! top.users.where(['not exists (select i_s.done from ideas i join idea_subscriptions i_s on i_s.idea_id=i.id join line_tops lt on lt.idea_id=i.id where i_s.user_id=users.id and i_s.done=? and lt.top_id=?) and exists (select i_s.done from ideas i join idea_subscriptions i_s on i_s.idea_id=i.id join line_tops lt on lt.idea_id=i.id where i_s.user_id=users.id and i_s.done=? and lt.top_id=?)', false, top.id, true, top.id])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
top = Top.find(top_id)
top.users.includes(:idea_subscriptions).where("idea_subscriptions.done = true")
```

Comment: As for me you have some mess in models's relations. Try to simplify user -> ideas chain.

Comment: I deleted my comment in fact it was just because I wasn't writing subscriptions correctly xD Now I've got "SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: ideas.done" see http://pastebin.com/VYEPm1h5

Comment: It says that you should create this column for model via migration or `attr_accessor`

Comment: Yeah but the fact is that i did that and i check in the sqlite database done (stored as t or f) attribute is present in idea_subscriptions. Strange ?

Comment: So you need to filter results by `done` field in Idea model or in IdeaSubscription?

Comment: done belongs to the IdeaSubscription model. (as it is per user)

Comment: I have updted my post. Post me if it helps.

Comment: OK I managed to do it I think ! Thanks for your help ! @top.users.includes(:ideas).where("idea_subscriptions.done = ?", true)